# How to open form when a specific cell in DataGridView Single-click in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   a   |   b   |   c   |   d   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1.  |   b1  |   c1  |   d1  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The problem is how to make a cell ex: b1 click and a form will show? but when c1 or d1 clicked the form won't open, the only cursor on the place c1 or d1.

I already use CellClick event but all of the cells when I click will open the form, that's not what I want. I use VB.NET.

Comment: test *which actual cell* was clicked in cellclick - VB isn't a mind reader, and cannot know to only raise a click event when you click B1 but not C1 - it raises for every click and then you have to program it to decide whether to take action

Comment: if  i m click on c1 then open form...! How to open ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`. They are passed to the click event as `e`. The index of the first row of data (not including the headings) is 0. The colums are also indexed starting with 0. So, in your diagram column c would be index 2. You will find that .net indexes start at 0.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex = 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        Form2.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the _CellMouseUp event like:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseUp(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseUp
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    j = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    If i = 5 And j = 2 Then
        MsgBox(i & "  " & j)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the Form Open code...? I want to Click on cell then show Form how to do please help me

Comment: @ Dr Aryan--- get the coordianates of the cell,  i and j, you want to open the form  and replace the msgbox line with yourformName.show

Comment: Yes its Work thanx a lot man thanx

Comment: I'm most amused at the dichotomy between your username and the posted code